# Techniques to master about implementing a network player

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, network-programming

I have a final project abount database design this semester. And my teacher gives us many tasks for alternatives, such as Student Information Management System, Airline Reservation System and so on. However, I want to design such a player that it allows users to upload their own works and share together. Of course it also provides download service. I'm a sophomore this year. I'm familiar with c++ programming, but do not know much about network programming. Furthermore, I learnt T-SQL this semester and also did some works on MySQL in java(course in this semester, too). My idea is here (I have drew a picture):http://tmjfzy.blog.163.com/blog/static/66447025201242553045/
I need some advice about network programming. Could you give me some to help me realize my imagination? Thank you :-).

Comment: Any reason to use QT and C++ rather than C# where everything is easier?

Comment: @Lap "Everything" is easier in C#? That's a bold statement

Comment: Because I'm familiar with it. And C# is really very nice and powerful. I only have 3 weeks, and WPF is not familiar to me. Furthermore, what about the network part? Could you give me some concrete advice. I think it's possible for me to reconsider. Because I have been in a team doing picture processing following a processor in my department. And I used emgu.cv with C# last semester, but this semester I use opencv instead of emgu.cv. My professor also asks me why not C#. I say I'm familiar with C++. He also asks me how to deal with parallel programming with C++, it's really easy in C#...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're basically reinventing YouTube but with dedicated client?

Actually it's very easy to start without any clients or C++ : all you need is a server with MySQL, Apache and PHP. I recommend WAMP server if you're on Windows. FlowPlayer is a flash video player quite easy to integrate, but today using HTML5 video features should be a better idea. I believe you can have the reference Web system up and running in about 3 to 6 days.
(I'm also a C++ programmer and I had no problem with learning enough HTML, PHP and JavaScript to do very similar thing ).

Once you have a system up and running (possibly with limitation on video file format) you can design and implement API. From server side it's nothing more than PHP files, just returning data in your format of choice (eg. JSon, XML) instead of generating HTML.
With server-side API done, you can start working on client. Registration, login, upload from file and download to file should go first. Once the client can get the video files, you can implement a player. A streaming player goes next. If you encounter problems with playing back the video files, this is good moment to break compatibility with web version and change video file format. Now that you know what playback formats are supported, you might implement converting before upload. (Conversion makes sense if you want to have all files on server in one format. Otherwise it's not really usefull: if a client can convert a video, it should be able to play it back. This means all other clients also should understand the format and be able to play it back.)

At this point you can consider rewriting the server. Or other student can be writing the server in the same time as you're busy with client.
Having working Apache-PHP reference all the time makes such parallelism a breeze.

All the above requires using HTTP as underlying protocol. I think Qt has built in support. If not you can use some library (like cURL) or implement it from scratch on sockets.
Eventually streaming, like RTP+RTSP, can be added for playback.

If you feel really adventurous, you can start designing your own protocol, but this is the very last step, after having both own client and own server working flawlessly on hand-implemented HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it's really good. However, because of the limitation of time and manpower(3 weeks and only one person me), I think I will not build the website. So I just want the client to get data from or upload data to the server. And just now a new idea occurred to me. Is it workable that if I write an application(A) on the server and let it connect with the applications(B) on clients, and A is in charge of returning the search results, transmitting data to B, receiving data from B and doing changes to database? And any advice for this idea? Thanks :-)

Comment: Building the test website is like 1 day if you know PHP, and 3 days if you don't. The looks, graphic and CSS is what takes most time building normal website, and you don't need them here.


Yeah, application A is the server (in the software, not hardware meaning) and B is the client. It's the standard client-server architecture. I thought that was the idea from the beginning. In what I wrote, the Apache+PHP is A and webbrowser is B. Then you replace them with your C++ applications.

Comment: Wow! sounds great! I'll consider about it. By the way, I know HTML and CSS. Just now I had a look at PHP's grammar, it's like C, right? And thanks again for the advice. Love u.